# Conditional formatting in Google Sheets with 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet where column E lists statuses of jobs and column N has the due date for the job. What I'd like to do is colour code the date so that the date appears red if the due date is before today's date and the status is any other status other than complete. Would appreciate some help on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a *Custom formula* in your Conditional format rules. Suggested formula:

`=AND(E1<>"complete", N1<TODAY())`